# Calculate $\frac{d}{dx}(\cos(\sin(\cos(\sin(...(\cos(x)))))))$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, derivatives, trigonometric-integrals

> Calculate:
> $$\frac{d}{dx}(\cos(\sin(\cos(\sin(...(\cos(x)))))))$$

This looks kind of daunting but I decided to see what happens to the derivative for a section of the function. If I consider:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\cos(\sin(\cos(\sin(\cos(x))))))$$

Then I can set $f=\cos(u)$ and $u=\sin(\cos(\sin(\cos(x))))$. I can then apply the chain rule: $$\frac{df(u)}{dx}=\frac{df}{du} \cdot \frac{du}{dx} \implies \frac{d}{du}(\cos(u)) \cdot \frac{d}{dx}(\sin \left(\cos \left(\sin \left(\cos \left(x\right)\right)\right)\right))$$

We know that:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(\cos(u))=-\sin(u)$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}(\sin \left(\cos \left(\sin \left(\cos \left(x\right)\right)\right)\right))=\left(-\sin \left(u\right)\right)\cos \left(\cos \left(\sin \left(\cos \left(x\right)\right)\right)\right)\sin \left(\sin \left(\cos \left(x\right)\right)\right)\cos \left(\cos \left(x\right)\right)\sin \left(x\right)$$

Therefore:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\cos(\sin(\cos(\sin(\cos(x))))))=-\sin \left(\sin \left(\cos \left(\sin \left(\cos \left(x\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\cos \left(\cos \left(\sin \left(\cos \left(x\right)\right)\right)\right)\sin \left(\sin \left(\cos \left(x\right)\right)\right)\cos \left(\cos \left(x\right)\right)\sin \left(x\right)$$

Not the nicest result but nonetheless a result. I thought I could use this to help me solve the original question, however I'm not sure how I can do that. Since the function starts and ends with $\cos$, only on the second nest the result is this massive and complex.

Therefore; I'd like to ask if anyone can hint and guide me in the right direction!

Comment: Have you tried to approach the question by using induction?

Comment: What does exactly the ellipsis in the beginning mean? $n$ times $\cos(\sin(\ldots))$? Infinity times? Then $f(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)$, $f_0(x)=x$, $f_n(x)=\cos(\sin(f_{n-1}(x)))$ and you can use implicit differentiation after taking limit like $f'=(\cos(\sin(f)))'$ and then the chain rule, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f_{1}(x) = \cos(x), \ f_{n}(x) = \cos(\sin(f_{n-1}(x)))$

$f_{1}(x)^{\prime} = -\sin(x), \ f_{n}(x)^{\prime} = -\sin(\sin(f_{n-1}(x))) \cdot \cos(f_{n-1}(x)) \cdot f_{n-1}(x)^{\prime}$

So if you'd like to compute $f_{n}(x)^{\prime}$ at some particular point $x_{0}$ you need to make a step-by-step computation: first compute $f_{1}(x_{0})^{\prime}$, then plug it into $f_{2}(x_{0})^{\prime} = -\sin(\sin(f_{1}(x_{0}))) \cdot \cos(f_{1}(x_{0})) \cdot f_{1}(x_{0})^{\prime}$ and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The equation $\cos(\sin(t)) = t$ has a single solution, $t=0.768\ldots$. So if by $\cos(\sin(\cos(\sin(...(\cos(x))))))$ you mean this constant, then the derivative is the derivative of a constant, $\frac{d}{dx}0.768\ldots=0$.

Comment: If the OP has ended it in a $\cos x$, shouldn't that mean that trigonometric functions are finite? If yes, one can't write $\cos(\sin(t))=t$.